# Loading Spinner Using spsComps::addLoader in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I made a very simple Shiny app that has just two dropdown inputs. The second input is dependent on the first. The last thing I would like to add is a **loading spinner for the second dropdown input `vars_subspecies`**.

I was able to achieve this spinner using `spsComps::addLoader` without using modularity but it's not working when I use modules.

Here is a fully working example:

```
### global.R
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

source("tab1_ui.R", local = T)
source("tab1_server.R", local = T)

# Create sub_species column
iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(
    subspecies = case_when(
      startsWith(as.character(Species), "setosa") ~ rep(c("setosa1", "setosa2"), length.out = n()),
      startsWith(as.character(Species), "versicolor") ~ rep(c("versicolor1", "versicolor2"), length.out = n()),
      startsWith(as.character(Species), "virginica") ~ rep(c("virginica1", "virginica2"), length.out = n())
    )
) 


### ui.R
fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dropdownsUI("dropdowns")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
    )
  )
)


### server.R
function(input, output, session) {
  subspeciesServer("dropdowns")
}


### tab1_ui.R
dropdownsUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id) 
  
  tagList(
    selectInput(ns("speciesDropdown"), label = "Species:", choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")),
    
    div(
      id = "subspecies_container",
      uiOutput(ns("subspeciesDropdown"))
    )
  )
}


### tab1_server.R
subspeciesServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    dependent_subspecies <- reactive({
      iris2 %>%
        filter(Species == req(input$speciesDropdown)) %>% 
        pull(subspecies) %>%
        unique()
    })
    
    subspecies_loader <- spsComps::addLoader$new(target_selector = "subspecies_container")
    
    output$subspeciesDropdown <- renderUI({
      subspecies_loader$show()
      on.exit({subspecies_loader$hide()})
      
      Sys.sleep(1)
      
      selectInput("vars_subspecies", "Sub Species:", choices = dependent_subspecies())
    })
      
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are missing a `ns` in your UI:

```r
        div(
            id = ns("subspecies_container"),
            uiOutput(ns("subspeciesDropdown"))
        )
```

Remember in all module elements, anytime you use ID, `ns` is required.